# How to get all results from azure search?

Tags: azure, logic, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

Currently I am creating an application where I need to call API for azure search. Calling this API :

```
https://<searchServiceName>.search.windows.net/indexes/<index-name>/docs/search?api-version=2016-09-01
```

Also providing all required parameters with search query as :

```
(test||test||test||test||test||test||test)+ Contacts+Campaigns+Companies+Targets+Complanits+Claims+Activities+Opportunities+Completed Activities
```

Problem is , there are total 1127 rows in table related to this particular search. But I get only first fifty of them with following JSON object output.

```
"@search.nextPageParameters": {
        "search": "(test||test||test||test||test||test||test)+ Contacts+Campaigns+Companies+Targets+Complanits+Claims+Activities+Opportunities+Completed Activities",
        "skip": 50}
```

What changes I should make in query so that I can get all 1127 or more results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected behavior. From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) (See documentation about `$top` query parameter):

> **$top=# (optional)**
>
> The number of search results to retrieve. **This defaults to 50**. When
>   calling via POST, this parameter is named top instead of $top. **If you
>   specify a value greater than 1000 and there are more than 1000
>   results, only the first 1000 results will be returned, along with a
>   link to the next page of results (see @odata.nextLink in the example
>   below).**
>
> Azure Search uses server-side paging to prevent queries from
>   retrieving too many documents at once. The default page size is 50,
>   while the maximum page size is 1000. This means that by default Search
>   Documents returns at most 50 results if you don't specify $top. If
>   there are more than 50 results, the response includes information to
>   retrieve the next page of at most 50 results (see @odata.nextLink and
>   @search.nextPageParameters in the Examples below. Similarly, if you
>   specify a value greater than 1000 for $top and there are more than
>   1000 results, only the first 1000 results are returned, along with
>   information to retrieve the next page of at most 1000 results.

Based on this, there are a few things you would need to do:

1. Specify a value for `$top` parameter. Because you're not specifying any value, default number of records (which is 50) are returned.
2. Since a single request can only fetch a maximum of 1000 records and you mentioned that the index contains more than 1000 records, you will need to issue multiple queries to fetch paged results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Have another issue for same operation. Please have a look  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714067/how-to-get-a-link-to-fetch-next-records-from-azure-search